# Spring websocket + Spring boot embedded tomcat issue

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I have weird scenario that i cannot reproduce, it just happens.
Anyone know what it is and why this is happening. I causes my application to force restart or else nothing works.

```
[INFO ] 2016-02-18 16:41:03.584 [http-nio-8443-exec-1] WsRemoteEndpointImplServer - Failed to close the ServletOutputStream connection cleanly
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:51) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.flush(SecureNioChannel.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.close(SecureNioChannel.java:413) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.NioServletOutputStream.doClose(NioServletOutputStream.java:138) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletOutputStream.close(AbstractServletOutputStream.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doClose(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:142) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.close(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:638) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.onWritePossible(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:117) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.doWrite(WsRemoteEndpointImplServer.java:80) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.writeMessagePart(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:450) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessage(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:338) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.startMessageBlock(WsRemoteEndpointImplBase.java:270) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.sendCloseMessage(WsSession.java:584) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsSession.onClose(WsSession.java:520) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.close(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:163) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.access$200(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:48) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler$WsReadListener.onDataAvailable(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:194) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractServletInputStream.onDataAvailable(AbstractServletInputStream.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.AbstractProcessor.upgradeDispatch(AbstractProcessor.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:669) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_40]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_40]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar!/:8.0.30]
```